# Swift SQL Query (with php) to CSV

Tags: php, ios, mysql, swift

is it possible to fetch data from a mysql query with the help of php and generate a csv file and send it in an email (in swift)?

Actual i create some tableviews in my xCode project. I fetch the data from my database with a php file and the put them into NSDictionaries and generate objects out of the dictionaries. 
Can i create a CSV file out of NSDicationary ?

Thanks in advance